# How to install JDK 1.6 on Mac OSX Leopard?

Tags: macos, java, osx-leopard, java-6

How can I install JDK 1.6 on Mac OSX Leopard?

In Software Update today I updated Java, and it upgraded from `1.5.0_26` to `1.5.0_28` (This is not 1.6!). I have Xcode Tools installed, version 3.0. On the download site it didn't list Mac.

Comment: Java updates usually cover all recent versions. I believe the latest updates are for 1.4, 1.5, and 1.6. See which ones you have under /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

Comment: You must have Leopard 10.5.7 + and 64bit hardware for the Java SE 6.

Comment: In /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions version 1.6 is installed, but the current is 1.5 is the current version. How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened Java Preferences and made Java SE 6 the first version to use

Answer (score 7):

JDK 6 (1.6) is preinstalled in both [OS X 10.5 and 10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4418). I actually didn't realize this, but it requires [64-bit hardware](http://blogs.oracle.com/cmar/entry/java_1_6_finally_available).

Until Mac OS X 10.7 (currently unreleased), the Java updates were maintained in-house by Apple. In 10.7, [Java will no longer be maintained by Apple](http://news.cnet.com/8301-31021_3-20020338-260.html).